# Laravel undefined method error on Storage Facade

Tags: php, laravel

I am having issues with Laravel Storage Facade.
When adding a method like getAdapter(), buildTemporaryUrlsUsing() or any other method that works with the Storage facade, Laravel returns the method undefined error if the disk is specified.

Example:

```
Storage::disk('local')->getAdapter(); // Undefined method 'getAdapter'.
```

However, when the disk is not specified, the error does not appear.

Example:

```
Storage::getAdapter();
```

How can i use these methods while specifying the disk? I am using Laravel 9.

Comment: Just tested in Tinker; `Storage::disk('local')->getAdapter()` returns an instance of `League\Flysystem\Local\LocalFilesystemAdapter` for me.

Comment: @ceejayoz Well for me this is only the case when not specifying the disk.

Comment: That's odd. In Tinker, if you do `Storage::disk('local')`, what is returned? It's `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter` here.

Comment: @ceejayoz In tinker, it returns League\Flysystem\Local\LocalFilesystemAdapter.

Comment: Has the default config changed for your local disk?

Comment: And does a fresh Laravel install demonstrate the same behavior?

Comment: As noted before, the config `config/filesystems.php` has a section called `disks`. The one you're trying to catch should be called `local`, if it's not present, it doesn't work. Add a simple test to see if it works in general `'test' => ['driver' => 'local', 'root' => storage_path('app'), 'throw' => false],`. `Storage::disk('test')` should return a `FilesystemAdapter` named test.

Comment: @dbf The local disk config is available in filesystems.php. Storage::disk('local') does return a FilesystemAdapter.

Comment: @Gavin the default local config is the default one: 
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

Comment: @MarcellinKhoury what does `storage_path('app')` return?

Comment: @dbf it returns the local path of the app directory on my pc, starting with /Users/.../storage/app

Comment: Ok, I would go so deep in Laravels framework debugging every line it uses for it try to return an adapter when setting the first argument as 'local'. I don’t think we can reproduce or comprehend anything from here. Never experienced a problem like yours.

Comment: @dbf the problem is not in the specific disk itself, but with any disk that is entered inside the disk method, maybe an intelephense problem?

Comment: Yes I understood the problem, what I meant is **debug the entire process** starting with `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager::disk()`, which is called by `Storage::disk`. Whereas `disk('local')`, `drive('local')` and `get('local')` basically try to return a disk given by `$name`. I would just debug the entire process to see where it goes sideways. Starting with `Storage::disk()`, which basically calls `$this->getDefaultDriver()` which accesses `$this->app['config']['filesystems.default']` to return the default disk name. Get where I'm going at? ;)